# Visual Studio 2019 Search History not in 'table'

Tags: visual-studio, search, visual-studio-2019, history

Alright so I recently did a clean install of visual studio and one thing changed from last time.

With vs2019, I think, came the different looking "Search History". Here are two screens of what exactly I mean with that. [New looking history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9gYw.png) and here [is the old one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC2Vc.png)

I'm just not sure why now I only get the old one. I found out that the new one only appears with CTRL + SHIFT + F and the older one with regular CTRL + F. Is there are way so that the default CTRL + F window displays the same output window? (the newest one)

At first I didn't really like it that much, but now I prefer it. I'm running VS2019 Version 16.5.2.

Edit: And also, this is where I used to get the table version if anyone was wondering. [image: prnt.sc/rue85b] Now it's just this old text thing.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Find in Files" tool window, ensure "Find results table" is selected, not "Find results 1 window":

[image]

Comment: VS 2019 Update to 16.5.2 (or possibly 16.5.1) has **totally** re-vamped the "Find in Files" dialog. No more "Results options" controls whatsoever.

Comment: @AdrianMole Ah - I'm using 16.4.6. Weird.

Comment: I only updated very recently. I was upset with the loss of a "Results window 2". However, there is now a "Lock" button in the top-bar of the find results window, that lets you open a new window for the next search ... and presumably *ad nauseam*. Change takes time to appreciate, I guess.

Comment: @AdrianMole I'm looking at the release notes for VS2019 16.5, 16.5.1, and 16.5.2 and they make no mention of changes to the Find-and-Replace dialogs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes

Comment: Yup, it looks totally different and I can't seem to find anything to change that.

Here is how it looks https://prnt.sc/rue7lb

Comment: And also, this is where I used to get the table version if anyone was wondering. https://prnt.sc/rue85b
Now it's just this old text thing like it used to be.

Comment: OK, let's try linking the images: [Find Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLy7l.png) and the new [Find Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itOTh.png). (Images are reduced to 50% size, which is why they look a bit fuzzy.)

Comment: Well that's exactly what I tried to say above. It only shows the table when using this. Sorry if that was not clear enough on my side

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the keyboard shortcut.

1. Go to Tools\Options
2. Navigate to Environment\Keyboard
3. Under "Show commands containing", type Edit.FindinFiles
4. Under "Press shortcut keys", press the desired keyboard shortcut (i.e. in your case Ctrl+F)
5. Click Assign and then OK

[See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94typ.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features > Check "Use
   Previous Find in Files"
2. Ctrl+Shift+F > Open Result options > Select
   "Find results table"
3. Close the Find and Replace tool window and
   revert the aforementioned "Use Previous Find in Files" setting
   (optional)
4. Perform a search (either Find in Files or simply through
   the standard Ctrl+F find prompt) Your results will then appear in
   the advanced tabular "Find results table" window.

Presumably this setting is also found elsewhere but I haven't been able to find it without turning off the Find in Files preview feature.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63789479