# Change find all / search all result interface in Visual Studio 2019 community

Tags: c#, search, visual-studio-2019

i dont like the new interface of my search all, it suddenly change when i reinstall my visual studio

here is my search all result interface
[image: find all 1]

the result suppose like this

[image: its suppose like this]

Do you guys know how to change the result interface ?

Comment: What is your Visual Studio version as displayed in the About dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using 2 different types of search.

The first capture you provide is from **Find and replace** feature, that cand be raised with shortcut `Ctlr + F`, and when you select option "Find all". It returns a lsit fo files that match the text you are searching for. You may check [Microsoft documentacion for Find and replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-replacing-text?view=vs-2019)

The second capture represent the usage of **Find references in your code**, that provides a way to find where particular code elements are referenced throughout your codebase. You can find more information in  [Microsoft documentacion for Find references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-references?view=vs-2019).

If you want to make use of **Find references** feature, you should use shortcut `Shift + F12` or simply you can make right click over any object/class/element in your code, and select option ***Find all references***.
[Capture: Find all references using right click and contextual menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Pkr.png)

Remember that **this would not work with a simple piece of text**, you must find references of an existant element, like a model, a class, a variable, etc.

Hope this info could be useful.

[EDIT]

Maybe I could misunderstand your question. If you refer to the theme (backgroud anf font color mainly) of the interface, you could set *Light* theme option, through main menu, selecting **Tools** menu, and then **Options**. once there, enter section **General**, under **Environment** option, and select **Light** option in dropdownlist associated with **Color theme** option.

Check this link (made for VS CE 2017, but work as well) to see captures of the process:
https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/869/how-to-change-to-a-dark-theme-in-visual-studio-community-2017

[EDIT FOR COMMENT]

I've checked it with VS 2019. As you said, default view for **Find all** feature looks like references result view. If you want to keep the "classic" list view, you can simply click on ***ListView*** button, at the right top, on the bar that appears over your result section, as you can see in following capture. [image]

Comment: thank you for answering, before i reinstall my visual studio 2019, the ctrl + f and then find all always show result of references feature, how do i change it back ?

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I had to install VS 2019 and try. Please, check answer again, I edited to inlcude a solution that worked for me, and let me know if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for your great effort for helping me mr dave, but i dont found litview in my search
https://imgur.com/27dQJjz

Comment: as you can see i use 2 kind of search in visual studio 2019 ( ctrl + f and ctrl + shift + f )
and the problem is in my search ( ctrl + f ) doesnt have List View
https://imgur.com/TwPdFvJ

Comment: It seems that, when the new 2019 result window is closed, you are not able to find it again (as it should appear under _**View>Find**_ Result menu options), as you can check in this reported bug: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/477146/menu-options-exist-for-find-results-1-and-find-res.html. And, as far as I can see for the captures you've sent, you are watching results in the old **Find Results 1** container, and I found no reference of the Results table in the menu.

Comment: so what should i do ?

Comment: Please, check if activating old Find & Replace feature gives you an option to view results in **Results table**. For this, go to _**Tools>Options**_, enter section _**Environment>Preview features**_ and enable _**Use previous Find in Files**_. With this optiona ctivated, you might be able to locate Find result table, under the _**View>Find Results**_ menu. This does not correct absolutely the problem, which seeems to be provider's responsibility, but maybe serves as a workaroud. Please, let me know.

Comment: it only change the ( ctrl + shift + f ) feature, and also there is no **View>Find Result**

Comment: When you use `Ctrl + Shift + F`, you can set _**Results table**_ in section _**Result options**_. If you enable this option, and click _**Find All**_, the window must be displayed, and once displayed you can use it and it must appear inside the menu. Is this working for you?

Comment: Apparently, this post has describes the same problem you are having: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61071004/visual-studio-2019-search-history-not-in-table. As was not able to reproduce exactly the problem with the last release I've downloaded, could you please detail which version are you using? You can find it on menu _**Help>About Microsoft Visual Studio**_

Comment: thank you for your great effort, i really appreciate it

Comment: here is my version Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.6.5

Comment: You're welcome! I'm afraid that I have the same version and, as it seems to be a software bug, I am not able to offer you a proper solution. All I can suggest is to rollback to default settings (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2019) or even make a new clean install of the product (if you haven't done yet).

Comment: Moreover, you could try opening a bug request with Microsoft (which seems that's already been done). Until Microsoft provides a working relase, maybe other users could bring light over this case or help you with useful advice. I wish I could offer you more but I'm running out of ideas. I'm sorry.

Comment: I've noticed rigth now that Microsoft has released a new version (16.7.0) of VS Community 2019. If it is not a real inconvenience in your situation, I would recomemend you to try with a clean install of this version.