# How to enable visual studio find results window with "advanced features"?

Tags: settings, visual-studio-2019

Please refer to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoPRj.jpg) for the 2 types of `Find results window` I've encountered in VS2019 using the Quick find feature (or the default Ctrl+F).

The first image is a window that seems advanced, in that it has grouping of the results (by project, by file), it has other options like the `Keep results`, and `List view` toggles, etc etc.

The second image on the other hand is a really plain results list, without the options/features of the first one.

**For the first window**, I don't remember anymore how I've done it (I've started using VS2019 early last year), and for the succeeding VS installations, I'm only using this with a **settings file exported** from VS.

**For the second window**, I tried to reset VS settings (`Tools` → `Import and Export Settings`) and selected C#, and when I use quick find and see its results, it is this kind of find results window that is shown.

I really want to reset VS settings, but I cannot lose the features provided by the first Find result window.

**Question**: How to enable that window?

Sub question if I may - the reason I want to reset VS settings is that changes I make in `Text Editor` → `C#` → `Code Style` does not take effect and is reset (I make the changes, press OK button, open the options window again, and the values are reverted - even after restarting VS). What may have caused this behavior?

**VS Version**: Enterprise 2019, 16.6.5

Answer (score 10):

It took me some time to figure out. There isn't a Find Result Window 1 and 2 anymore. After you perform a search, in the "Find" results pane, there is a "Keep Results" button. Click this button to lock the pane so that the next time you search, it will create a new "Find" results pane and keep the locked pane visible.

[image: Find Pane - Keep Results]

Answer (score 5):

1. Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features > Check "Use Previous Find in Files"
2. Ctrl+Shift+F > Open Result options > Select "Find  results table"
3. Close the Find and Replace tool window and revert the aforementioned "Use Previous Find in Files" setting (optional)
4. Perform a search (either Find in Files or simply through the standard Ctrl+F find prompt)

Your results will then appear in the advanced tabular "Find results table" window.
Presumably this setting is also found elsewhere but I haven't been able to find it without turning off the Find in Files preview feature.

Comment: Unfortunately the option no longer exists, so sadly you no longer have the choice between the old and new layout.